# SQL find the address?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Im trying to find mortals who have a certain address.

I have what I believe to be the right code but no matter what I do to the 'WHERE' clause, I get no results returned.

Create a unique list of first and last names for anyone living at 4389 Jaffa Terrace S.

**I'VE TRIED**

```
SELECT MORTAL.FIRST_NAME||' '||MORTAL.LAST_NAME "4389_Jaffa_Terrace_S"
FROM MORTAL 
JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1 LIKE  '%4389%';


SELECT FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME "4389_Jaffa_Terrace_S"
FROM MORTAL
JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID:
WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1 LIKE  '%4389%';

SQL> SELECT FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME "4389_Jaffa_Terrace_S"
  2  FROM MORTAL
  3  JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
  4  JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
  5  WHERE UPPER(ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1) LIKE  '%4389%';

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME "4389_Jaffa_Terrace_S"
  2  FROM MORTAL
  3  JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
  4  JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
  5  WHERE UPPER(ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1) LIKE  '%JAFFA%';

SQL> SELECT FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME "4389_Jaffa_Terrace_S"
  2  FROM MORTAL
  3  JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
  4  JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
  5  WHERE SUBSTR(ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1,0,4) LIKE  '4389';

no rows selected
```

EDITED TO ADD:

```
SQL> desc mortal
 Name
 --------------------------
 MORTAL_ID
 SEX_TYPE_CODE
 FIRST_NAME
 LAST_NAME
 DOB
 MARITAL_STATUS_CODE
 SSN
 MIDDLE_NAME
 WORK_PHONE

SQL> desc Mortal_address
 Name
 --------------------------
 ADDRESS_ID
 MORTAL_ID

SQL> desc address
 Name
 --------------------------
 ADDRESS_ID
 ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE
 ZIP_CODE
 STATE_CODE
 ADDRESS_LINE1
 CITY
 ADDRESS_LINE2
 ADDRESS_LINE3
 COUNTRY
```

Comment: Do you get anything without the where clause? Is your join correct/

Comment: Can you show us the DDL for MORTAL and MORTAL_ADDRESS, along with data from those tables that should be returned?  That would really help in identifying the problem.

Comment: Ok, hold on, Ill edit my post

Comment: Michael, This is a multi-table join, single table select, 1 column w/ the names, namead as above-I have it right except for the WHERE clause, I believe......**Now Edited**  Please answer/comment normally, so I can check/up-tick you guys, thanks!

Comment: 'SQL> select * from ADDRESS where ADDRESS_LINE1 like '%4389%'
  2  ;
ADDRESS_ID A ZIP_CODE        ST ADDRESS_LINE1
---------- - --------------- -- -------------------------
ADDRESS_LINE2                                           A
------------------------------------------------------- -
        29 H 46927           IN 4389 JAFFA Terrace S.


        30 H 46927           IN 4389 Jaffa Terrace S.
'

Comment: Should there be another `||` between MORTAL.LASTNAME and "4389_Jaffa_Terrace_S"?

Answer (score 3):

try debugging step-by-step.

first:

```
select * from address where address_line1 like '%4389%'
```

then, for any address returned,

```
select * from Mortal_address where address_id = <the address_id that was returned from above>
```

then,

```
select * from mortal where mortal_id = <the mortal_id that was returned from above>
```

maybe this will show where your joins are not joining correctly ??

Comment: My steps would be slightly different.  After the first query, I'd repeat it, but with a join.  By the way, my vote on this question pushed your reputation into 4 digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @DanBracuk -- agree with your idea ... and, thanks for the uptick - add it to the list:  http://youowemeabeer.com/